# Running OS X Yosemite, but About This Mac shows Version 10.90

Tags: macos

In About this Mac it shows that the OS is Yosemite but the version number is 10.90. Is this normal? I thought Yosemite is 10.10, and Mavericks was 10.9.

[image: OS X Yosemite Version 10.90]

Comment: Your Installation did not go so well :)

Comment: 10.90 would appear to be one of the beta builds. 'fix' seems to be to install the release over it.

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest Yosemite installer from the Mac App Store but do not install it.

Copy following in to your Terminal to verify the downloaded Yosemite file is correct:

```
shasum /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
```

Wait for a minute for it to calculate. The result for the previous version should be:

```
eebf02a20ac27665a966957eec6f5e6fe3228a19  /Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
```

And for Yosemite Download as of Nov. 27 the result is:

```
a673c2c6d967f4da2934b7d6cf3736936970b194  /Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg
```

Proceed with Install.

Comment: I'm getting: a673c2c6d967f4da2934b7d6cf3736936970b194  /Applications/Install OS X Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg, when trying to install it prompts "This copy of the “Install OS X” application is too old to be opened on this version of OS X."

Comment: hmm, my download is from Nov 7 !

Comment: mine is from today, but anyway, I can't install it.. ideas?

Comment: I am re-downloading it to double check. another 40 minutes to wait to confirm. Your checksum is strange for now, do not use it.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate that :)

Comment: OK, I had a older version, then today's version is same as yours a673c2c6d967f4da2934b7d6cf3736936970b194

Comment: If you have duplicate version of the "Install OS X Yosemite" (copy) delete the old one and try to install, or use the cmd-r to rebuild from Internet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19015/discussion-between-andpy-and-buscar).

Answer (score 1):

Mmmh, maybe you've changed it yourself and forgotten about it?

Changing OS X version to 10.90 has been suggested to solve some compatibility issues, e.g. with Matlab (see [MATLab crashes on launch OS X Yosemite](https://superuser.com/questions/764282/matlab-crashes-on-launch-os-x-yosemite)).

To change it back to 10.10, type the following in a Terminal window:

```
sudo nano /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```

then change the value under 'ProductVersion' to 10.10 or whatever version you fancy.